# Angular karma test failing due to unknown provider of injected value recipe

Tags: angularjs, testing, karma-runner

Before posting this question, I have researched a lot regarding the "unknown provider" error but I could not find anything like my scenario.

Basically in my app.js were I have defined my main app module, called - "bookingsApp", I am adding a value recipe to it, called - "connectionWithServerErrorMessage".

Then, I am accessing this value recipe, in a service, called - "httpPostingExampleService". Till now no issues. Note that the test for this service passes correctly.

The problem comes, when I call the method that there is in this service in another service. For example, in this case the service, called - "bookingElementExampleService". Please see plunkr for a better understanding: `http://plnkr.co/edit/0Z3ZiQXPGdkD08r9Akci`

The problem is that when I come to test this other service (bookingElementExampleService), it fails because of the following error:

```
Error: Unknown provider: connectionWithServerErrorMessageProvider <- connectionWithServerErrorMessage <- httpPostingService
```

Note: The application works just fine, no errors are outputted, the problem is just with that test failing.

Honestly I could not understand, I think I have all the module dependencies set correctly, so can't really pin point what is the issue. Any help please?

**Update**

Here is my karma config files:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        //First include all dependencies
        'app/lib/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js',
        'bower_components/qtip2/jquery.qtip.js',
        'app/lib/angular/angular.js',
        'app/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
        'bower_components/angular-debounce/dist/angular-debounce.min.js',
        'app/lib/ui-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-0.12.0.min.js',
        //Then include application and any module definitions which are required to be loaded first
        'app/app.js',
        'app/components/http-posting/http-posting.js',
        'app/components/booking-element/booking-element.js',
        'app/components/bookings/bookings-ui.js',
        'app/components/date-and-stats/date-and-stats.js',
        'app/components/timeline/timeline.js',
        //Then include all other files required
        'app/*.js',
        'app/components/**/*.js',
        //Then include all partial files
        'app/components/**/*.html' //html files (partials)
    ],
```

Comment: Is the module containing `connectionWithServerErrorMessage` loaded and/or listed as a resource in your Karma config?

Comment: Just a long shot. What happens if you add `beforeEach(angular.mock.module('bookingsApp'));` to your test? The value is part of your `bookingsApp` module which will not get initialized in your test.

Comment: @Anzeo yes, please see the updated description for the list of files in my karma config

Comment: @AndreasHoffmann it works that way and it makes sense in a way, but still then I can't understand why the test of the service, called - "httpPostingExampleService", passes correctly without having to do this.